# Mystical white stripe at bottom on Safari iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, sticky-footer

I have a website where an unwanted white stripe is appearing at the very bottom, and this only for mobile Safari iOS visitors.

I'm using the following code for the footer area to stick it to the bottom:

```
<div class="page_wrapper">
    <!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer_sticker">    
        <div class="footer_upper">
            <!-- Content here -->
        </div>
        <div class="footer_lower">
            <!-- Content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



#footer, .page_wrapper:after {
    height: 275px;
}
.page_wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.page_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: -275px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
}
#footer .footer_sticker {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 275px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. Can you fix it or remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Question from bygone era but, I encountered the issue today, when changing the view from portrait orientation to landscape. So here's my solution:

**My Research:**

*NOTICE:* When changing from portrait to landscape - the `address-bar` is hidden and when you change back to portrait (from landscape) the `address-bar` appears slowly (takes a split sec). **THAT'S THE PROBLEM!**.

You see, that magical white strip at the bottom is almost the same height as `address-bar + mobile top bar`

Basically CSS `height: 100%/100vh`is painted before all those magic happens and we get that annoying blank white bar at the bottom.

**How I solved**

By calculating the height of the document in a delay (of say 200ms) so I can get the final height of the document after all the effects and set the document height with the new value.

Here's what I meant:

```
var timerHandler;
timerHandler = setTimeout(() => {
   document.documentElement.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
}, 350)
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thanks so much man! I literally tried about 12 different solutions given on SO, twitter, macrumors forum and some random github repo issue posts, but nothing seemed to work besides this

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a 1-2 pixel white line appearing at the bottom of the page and to the right of the page on Safari 16.0 on macOS Monterey. After trying all sorts of things, the problem was solved by closing and re-opening the tab. I don't know how the tab acquired those extra pixels...